# Send email to assigned user in Task

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, workflow-tasks-list

I am using Sharepoint 2010. I am trying to send the email to the 'assigned to' user after the task been assigned.

I've marked 'Yes' in the advanced settings for 'Send e-mail when ownership is assigned?' However, when I assigned another user in the task, the user did not receive any email. What should I do?

[image: advanced settings]

p/s: I cant use SDP to solve this issue; permission not granted

Answer (score 0):

I assume you set the Email notification in a task list advanced settings. And if the user does not receive E-mail, we can first check if the Email works properly in your tenant.

Have a try to send an Email to the user with issue. Also make the user to check the Junk, make sure the Email has not been blocked by the Mailbox.

You can also test to create a new Alert which will send Email on item creation in the list. Through this we can check if SharePoint can properly send an Email to a user.

Comment: In addition to what @Jerry_MSFT suggested, the permissions on the task that is assigned should also be checked. A user must at least have read access (View List Items) for a task to receive an assignment notification for it.